# Run Azure Query using azure logic App and send email with the entire query output or query result as an attachment, Also schedule to run once in a day

Tags: azure

How to Run Azure Query using azure logic App and send email with the entire query output or query result as an attachment, Also schedule to run once in a day.

Already tried using azure alert rule but getting only row count in an email. I am looking for the entire query output to be displayed in the email body.

ContainerLog
| extend logEntry = parse_json(LogEntry)
| where logEntry.application.name contains `Application_name`
| where logEntry.hostname contains `application_name_service`
| where logEntey.error.message contains `error`
| project message= logEntry.error.message, timestamp=tostring(logEntry.timestamp)
| order by timestamp desc

Answer (score -1):

There is a really good example on running queries using Logic Apps and sending the results via email here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/automating-azure-workbook-queries-with-azure-logic-apps/ba-p/3728513

Alistair